# Latex Metropolis package - Default color for background of slides

Tags: beamer, color, beamer-metropolis

I am currently working on a presentation using the `Metropolis` package in Latex.
To add some matching figures, I was trying to find out what the default Hex color code for the background colour of the slides is in the package. I looked at both the documentation and the source code on Github, but could not find any clear answer there.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The colour is defined as `black!2` (which means 2% of black), this means RGB is roughly `250/250/250` and converted to HEX `#FAFAFA`

---

Personally I would simply create the figures with transparent background, this way colour discrepancies between different applications with different colour profiles cannot occur.

Comment: @h-man You're welcome and also welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: In case you are interested: it is stated in [beamercolorthememetropolis.dtx](https://github.com/matze/mtheme/blob/1a42fa19396c467a73f823f074dbef8c1211472d/source/beamercolorthememetropolis.dtx) lines 101-106.

Comment: @samcarter In fact I spend searching for this exact color and I had to compromise the color using Excel to get the exact number, it is `\definecolor{black2}{RGB}{27,55,61}`, which is very similar.